# How to scale down pure CSS Component to fit parent Component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, layout

I've built a pure css image, exported as a component in React. I'd like to scale down its size depending on the size of its parent.

I've attempted setting max sizes on the container className, object fit, and transform: scale. Either the pure css component disappears or doesn't change size. I can't figure out how to make it react responsively to its parent.

```
$shirt-color: #D2DADE;
$body-color: #F5EAD9;
$face-color: rgb(105, 97, 88);
$hair-color: rgb(177, 141, 107);
$background-color: #CCCCCC;

.body,
.head,
.neck-shadow,
.neck,
.ears,
.eyes,
.mouth,
.hair,
.glasses {
    position: relative;
}

.body {
    background: $shirt-color;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 50%; width: 55%;
    left: 23%; top: 75%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container {
    object-fit: scale;
    margin: 1%;
    width: 25vw; height: 25vw;
    max-width: 250px; max-height: 250px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: $background-color;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -20;
}

.ears {
    background: $body-color;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 10%; left: -10%;
    width: 22%; height: 20%;

    &::before {
        background: $body-color;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        top: 0%; left: 450%;
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
    } 
}

.mouth {
    border: 4px solid;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border-color: transparent transparent $face-color $face-color;
    top: -10%; left: 35%;
    width: 28%; height: 25%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.eyes {
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: rgba(241, 150, 30, 0.5);
    top: 0%; left: 44%;
    width: 10%; height: 15%;

    &::before, &::after {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        background: $face-color;
        border-radius: 100%;
        width: 100%; height: 60%;
        top: -20%;
    }
    &::before {
        left: -200%;
    }
    &::after {
        left: 200%;
    }
}

.hair {
    background: $hair-color;
    border-top-left-radius: 75%;
    border-top-right-radius: 75%;
    top: -10%; left: 0%;
    width:105%; height: 40%;

    &::before, &::after {
        background: $hair-color;
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
    }
    &::before {
        border-top-left-radius: 30%;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 75%;
        top: 75%; left: -17%;
        width: 22%; height: 110%;
    }
    &::after {
        border-top-right-radius: 30%;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 75%;
        top: 75%; left: 92%;
        width: 15%; height: 100%;
    }
}

.hair .hair-content {
    &::before, &::after {
        background: $hair-color;
        border-radius: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        top: 40%;
    }
    &::before {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
        left: 30%;
        width: 30%; height: 75%;
    }
    &::after {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 75%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 45%; height: 100%;
    }
}

.head {
    background: $body-color;
    border-radius: 40px;
    left: 12%; top: -111%;
    width: 75%; height: 80%;
    z-index: 5;
  }

.neck {
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(179, 170, 157) 49%, $body-color 49%, $body-color );
    border-radius: 45%;
    border-color: #444 #444 #444 #444;
    left: 42%; top: -15%;
    width: 15%; height: 25%; 
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Bradley.scss'

export default class Bradley extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className = 'container' >
                    <div className = 'head'>
                        <div className = 'hair'>
                            <div className = 'hair-content'/>
                        </div>
                        <div className = 'ears'/>
                        <div className = 'eyes'/>
                        <div className = 'mouth'/>
                        <div className = 'neck'/>
                    </div>
                    <div className = 'body'/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And then I render it inside of a Jumbotron, for example. I've tried nesting it within other elements and a Container component.

```
import React from 'react';
import Bradley from './components/Bradley/Bradley'
import {Row, Col, Jumbotron, Container} from 'react-bootstrap'
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Jumbotron>
          <Bradley/>
      </Jumbotron>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The image stays the same size, and overflows from the container. Resizing the window does nothing.

EDIT: It now fits well, and I use % for all heights and widths, but it looks awful when I shrink the screen,
[image]

[image]

Comment: Just use percentages for all your dimensions/positions.

Comment: All the clases that make the divs of your css image are defined with width and height as px, also the positions so they can't scale. You should change them to % or another unit that scales.

Comment: How can I maintain the aspect ratio with %?

Answer (score 0):

Change your dimension units to `%`, `scale` property will not work on hard coded dimensions, like `32px`

Comment: I've changed it to use %, but when I adjust the screen size, I lose graphical fidelity. How can I make it scale with the parent without getting blurry?

Comment: Use breakpoints to determine how much the item should grow/shrink based on the current screen's size, scaling to 50% in a 1280px is not gonna look the same on a screen with 600px